# Playwright Test: Locator Behavior Inconsistent with Expectations

Tags: playwright

I'm encountering an issue with Playwright while testing my application. I have a test scenario, and here's the test case:

```
test('create a basic scenario', async ({ page }) => {
    await createScenario(page);
    expect(await page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Scenario 2' })).toBeEmpty();
});
```

In this test case, I expect a locator to be empty under certain conditions, but it's returning "notEmpty" when using expect.toBeEmpty(), and vice versa.

Here are the two scenarios:

When I expect the locator to be empty:

Error: expect(locator).toBeEmpty()
Locator: getByRole('heading', { name: 'Scenario 2' })
Expected: empty
Received: notEmpty

When I expect it not to be empty:

Error: expect(locator).not.toBeEmpty()
Locator: getByRole('heading', { name: 'Scenario 2' })
Expected: not empty
Received: empty

I'm looking for insights into why the locator behavior is inconsistent with my expectations and how to resolve this issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see an inconsistency. the result is not what you expect, but it's consistent. in addition please add a link to your app there is no way to help you without more details.

Comment: Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. What is `createScenario` and which page is under test?

Answer (score 1):

You should await **expect** and not the **locator**:

```js
await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Scenario 2' })).toBeEmpty();
```